# ¿Cómo configurar en un host compartido una aplicación web desarrollada en php 8 ( Gulp, Composer, Modernizr), basada en MVC y con bd Mysql?

Tags: php, mvc, host

No tengo muchos conocimiento y es mi primera aplicación, tampoco he subido nunca nada a un host, no se si alguien puede ayudarme.
[image: Estructura de mi aplicación en local]
Muestro la estructura de carpetas y archivos del proyecto, en la parte inferior de la imagen, se muestra en "terminal" como me situó en la carpeta Public para iniciar el servidor local.
La aplicación funciona perfectamente en localhost pero una vez subido a un host compartido en (“Hostinger”) solo se ve la página principal y los link no funcionan, me muestra la misma página.

[image: Estructura del proyecto subido al host "Hostinger"]
[image: Estructura en el host]
Arriba muestro la estructura del proyecto en el host.

Tengo una clase Router con varias funciones, esta controla las rutas(disponiendo unas rutas restringidas para el usuario normal)

```
public function comprobarRutas(){
  session_start();
  $auth=$_SESSION['login']?? null;
  $idU=$_SESSION['id'] ?? null;
  //RUTAS PROTEGIDAS
  $rutasProtegidas=['/admin','/servicios/crear'];
  $rutasAdministrador=['/admin',
  '/tecnicos/crear', '/tecnicos/actualizar','/tecnicos/eliminar']    
     $urlActual= $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ?? '/';
     $metodo= $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
  if($metodo==='GET'){
     $fn=$this->rutasGET[$urlActual] ?? null;  // tiene array con el controlador y método
        }else{
    $fn=$this->rutasPOST[$urlActual] ?? null;         }
   //proteger las rutas
  if(in_array($urlActual, $rutasProtegidas) && !$auth){  
 //busca la url actual, en las protegidas
  //no logueado
    header('Location: /');
   }else{ 
     if(in_array($urlActual, $rutasAdministrador) &&!$idU){ //logueado usuario normal                                    
      header('Location: /cita');
    }
   }


  if($fn){
     call_user_func($fn, $this);
  } else{
    echo "página no encontrada";
  }
```

}

$fn contiene un array con la función y su controlador correspondiente al link que pulsemos
$this contiene un array con las rutas, su controlador y su función

En localhost $fn varia su contenido, según el link pulsado, por ej. Link para ir al formulario de login.

```
array(2) {
         [0]=>
         string(27) "Controllers\LoginController"
         [1]=>
         string(5) "login"
     }
```

En Hostinger $fn contiene siempre:

```
array(2) {
         [0]=>
         string(29) "Controllers\PaginasController"
         [1]=>
         string(5) "index"
      }
```

Aunque pulse distintos links

$urlActual contiene la url que hemos pulsado en el link

```
$urlActual= $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ?? '/';
```

En Hostinger $urlActual siempre es null y nos lleva “/”.

---

Otra función en la clase Router es la siguiente

Esta función recibe la vista y los datos que pasaremos a la vista, en los controladores

```
public function render($view, $datos=[]){
     foreach($datos as $key=>$value){
             $$key=$value;        }
 ob_start(); 

 include __DIR__ . "/views/$view.php";
 $contenido= ob_get_clean();  // limpia memoria
 include __DIR__ . "/views/layout.php";
```

}

En localhost al presionar los links la función recibe $view, que es la ruta que corresponde a las vistas.
Por ejemplo presionamos el link de "login" y muestra "auth/login" y si fuera el link de "alta" mostraría "paginas/alta"

En Hostinger al presionar cualquier link, la $view que recibe la función, muestra siempre
"paginas/index", independientemente del link pulsado.

En otro archivo (index.php) tengo las rutas, muestro algunas.
Llamamos a la función get de la Clase Router, la cual tiene la ruta, nombre del controlador con su función correspondiente

```
 public function get ($url,$fn){
        $this->rutasGET[$url]=$fn;
    }

$router->get('/alta',[PaginasController::class,'alta']);
$router->post('/alta',[PaginasController::class,'alta']);
$router->get('/condicion',[PaginasController::class, 'informar']);
```

En localhost al pulsar por ejemplo, link de "alta", no dirige al get(/alta), llevándonos al archivo del controlador correspondiente y apuntando a la siguiente función.

```
public static function alta(Router $router){
    
    $usuario=new Usuarios;
    $errores=Usuarios::getErrores();
 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST'){

        $usuario= new Usuarios($_POST['usuario']);
                 
        $errores=  $usuario->validar();
       
          if(empty($errores)){
    
                    $usuario->guardar(null,'/login?resultado=6');
          }
              
    }
    $router->render('paginas/alta',[
        'errores'=>$errores,
        'usuario'=>$usuario
    ]); 

}
```

Pero en Hostinger todos los get de rutas nos llevan a la misma página principal, apuntando siempre “/”, en vez a las rutas que le corresponde

```
$router->get('/',[PaginasController::class,'index']);
```

Nos llevaría al archivo(que contiene la funciones de este controlador) que tiene la siguiente función, donde nos muestra la página principal, donde se usa la función “render”, que le indica la vista y los datos que le pasamos

```
  public static function index(Router $router){
    $inicio=true;
    $router->render('paginas/index',[
        'inicio'=>$inicio
    ]);
  }
```

He probado en Hostinger a sacar de la carpeta public (contiene archivo index con la rutas, una carpeta de imágenes, build con subcarpetas de css y js y sus archivos bundle.min.js y bundle.min.css), todas las carpetas y el index, adaptando en el index, la nueva ruta hacia archivo app, el cual contiene algunas funciones de control horario, la ruta al archivo de conexión a la base de datos, etc
require_once **DIR** . '/includes/app.php';
Dejando su contenido dentro de la carpeta del host "public_html", pero me daba error 500

Este es contenido actual del archivo .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^citasopticajose.online$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.citasopticajose.online$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

He probado añadiendo esto, pero sin resultado

```
AcceptPathInfo On
disable_path_info = On
```

Answer (score 0):

He utilizado otro Host "Heroku" y he tenido que añadir dos archivos al proyecto
un .htaccess con el siguiente código para tener permisos en las rutas:

```
 <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

y el otro archivo "Procfile" necesario para este host concreto

`web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/`

[image: situación de los archivo]

Modificar el archivo Router.php con el siguiente código:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])) {
    $urlActual = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ?? '/';
  } else {
    $urlActual = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '' ? '/' : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  }
```

Para entornos con Apache utilizamos 'PATH_INFO' y 'REQUEST_URI' para obtener correctamente las "urls" del Servidor
[image: cambios para obtener contenido Url]

Finalmente en el archivo ".gitignore" incluir los siguientes archivos para no incluirlos en producción: src, vendor, node_modules, gulpfile.js, package.json, package-lock.json y .env